# WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

It is an old question but I don't find the answer to my situation.

my code is a simple test code

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
 
url="http://news.163.com/"
chrome_options = Options()
# specify headless mode
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('–headless')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
browser.set_page_load_timeout(300)
browser.set_script_timeout(300)
browser.get(url)
title=browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="js_top_news"]/h2/a')
print(title[0].get_attribute('innerHTML'))
browser.quit()
driver.quit()
```

And I have added all the arguments in the options.
And `ps -aux |grep google-chrome` and kill all the process in my wsl.
Google Chrome 100.0.4896.88 with chrome-driver 100.0.4896.60 and they are in the same dir added in the environment path.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t) answer will help you.

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In wsl1, people can not use a linux version of chrome. so just use windows version chrome.exe and chromdriver.exe.
And my problem solved by simply `mv chromdriver.exe chromdriver`,because selenium can only identify chromdriver without '.exe'

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the updated version of the driver. Otherwise upgrade or downgrade your version to see if any of those work. This error is generally due to incompatibility

Comment: Thankyou, actually I can start with normal user. It seems to be problem bettween wsl1-chromedriver and windows-chromedriver.exe.

Answer (score 0):

*Google Chrome 100.0.4896.88* and *chrome-driver 100.0.4896.60* are perfectly in sync.

However as per the [documentation](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/help/chrome-doesn-t-start?authuser=0):

> > A common cause for Chrome to crash during startup is running Chrome as
> > root user (administrator) on Linux. While it is possible to work
> > around this issue by passing **`--no-sandbox`** flag when creating
> > your WebDriver session, such a configuration is unsupported and highly
> > discouraged. Please configure your environment to run Chrome as a
> > regular user instead.

---

### Solution

Remove the following arguments:

- *`--no-sandbox`*
- *`--disable-gpu`*
- *`--disable-dev-shm-usage`*
- *`disable-infobars`*

and execute your tests as ***non-root*** user (***non-administrator***) user.